# 301 Moved Permanently with ASP.net Web API and Https

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm using asp.net web forms with Web Api.
I can make the call over **http** no problem but if I use **https** then I get "301 Moved permanently"
I'm also using authorization.
Users are authorized using https.

On the API Control I have:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin,masteradmin")]

[HttpGet]
public string Delete(Guid id)
{
  return 'deleted'
}
```

my javascript:

```
 function DeleteItem(ID) {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/controlname/' + ID + '/Delete',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            //alert('deleted');
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert(ID + '\n' + x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
        }
    });
    }
```

again works fine over http but not with https.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Are you doing this in visual studio? 2010 or 2012? Or on a real server?

Comment: It's live on a real server (2003 iis 6). Developed with vs 2010. thanks

Comment: Just as an aside, you should probably not expose a destructive call (like Delete) to a GET request. A search engine crawling the site could accidentally delete your records! If you can't use the HTTP DELETE verb, then POST should be used instead.

Comment: Authentication is required but good point! thanks, I will modify it. Since it's ii6 modifying our 400+ website entries to allow http delete was not really a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the problem, was that in global.asax I had a redirection to non https for non admin directories. I excluded the "api" directory from the redirection and now it all works as it should

Answer (score 1):

if anyone has this issues but for a xamarin iOS application on a Mac, open the Reference.cs file. You can find it in the Web Reference folder in your project's three. Check to see if the url that you entered when you added the web reference and the one from the Reference.cs file are a match. I am referring to the url from the constructor of the Reference.cs class.  Especially pay attention to the http vs https part.